# Extreme difference in speed, read each line from file (fast) or from variable List<String> (very slow)

Tags: android, performance, arraylist, inputstreamreader

I create 2 different function that make the same thing:

Read one by one line and insert the value in a database.

The first (faster) read the information from a csv file;

```
load_voc(database, new InputStreamReader(myContext.getAssets().open(file_csv_vocaboli)));

private void load_voc(SQLiteDatabase db, InputStreamReader in ) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
    try {
        String line = null;
        //Legge la riga del CSV e la inserisce nella tabella tramite il metodo  getContentValues della classe Voc definita in fondo alla pagina
        int i=0;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            db.insert(Voc.TABLE_NAME, null, Voc.getContentValues(line));
            Log.i(TAG_i,"test: "+i);
            i++;
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

The second (very slow) take information from a variable List;

```
 private void load_voc_agg( List<String> csv_file_list_voc ) {
        String line = null;
        for(int i=0;i<csv_file_list_voc.size();i++){
            database.insert(Voc.TABLE_NAME, null, 
            Voc.getContentValues(csv_file_list_voc.get(i)));
            Log.i(TAG_i,"test: "+i);
        }
}
```

I also tried with

```
for(String s: csv_file_list_voc) {}
```

and

```
 Iterator<String> iterator = csv_file_list_voc.iterator();
 while(iterator.hasNext()) {}
```

with the same result.

I thought it was the second method the fastest but it is 20 times slower!

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What type of concrete List implementation are you passing to the load_vog_agg method (e.g. `ArrayList<String>`)?

Comment: Is a List<String> in each string there are items separed with coma

Comment: You can't create an instance of an abstract `List<String>` class. Your actual code must use a concrete class. Can you provide the code of the caller of the `load_voc_agg()` method to show what you are passing to it?

Comment: I used the answer of ישו אוהב אותך.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use transaction for multiple insert for faster speed. Should be something like this:

```
private void load_voc_agg( List<String> csv_file_list_voc ) {
  String line = null;
  database.beginTransaction();
  for(int i=0;i<csv_file_list_voc.size();i++){
    database.insert(Voc.TABLE_NAME, null, 
    Voc.getContentValues(csv_file_list_voc.get(i)));
    Log.i(TAG_i,"test: "+i);
  }
  database.setTransactionSuccessful();
  database.endTransaction();
}
```

Or you can use [SQLiteStatement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) with transaction:

```
private void load_voc_agg( List<String> csv_file_list_voc ) {
  String line = null;
  database.beginTransaction();
  String sql = "insert into" + Voc.TABLE_NAME + " (col1, col2) values (?, ?);";

  database.beginTransaction();
  SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);

  for(int i=0;i<csv_file_list_voc.size();i++){
    // Create your insert 
    statement.bindString(1, val1);
    statement.bindString(2, val2);

    long rowId = stmt.executeInsert();
    stmt.clearBindings();
  }
  database.setTransactionSuccessful();
  database.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: @davideinzaghi: Congrats! If this answer help your problem, please kindly accept as an Accepted Answer to close the question.